# List of dictionaries representing rows with datetime object to be loaded into database

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I have the below lines in a text file which I dumped from a database table using python.

> [{'id': 1, 'name': 'abcd', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 13, 18, 54, 40, 314716), 'comments': None, 'status': 'Success'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'efgh', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 14, 10, 4, 49, 9217), 'comments': None, 'status': 'Success'},...]

I want the read the file as a list and iterate over the dictionaries representing each row and load the database table.

The loading of this data from the file as a list in python works with ast.literal_eval but it works only in case there is no datetime object in the list inside file.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

However, when there is a datetime object present I get the following error:

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x000001C1A755D240>
```

Is there any way to read the data in file as a list of dictionaries in python such that it even works with the datetime object and thus its possible to load the data into the database table?

Any other way to load the rows into the database table from file would also help. The database I'm using is Postgres.

Comment: Stringifying Python objects to write them to files is usually a bad idea.  It might be better to use the tools in the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module, or to convert them to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `datetime.datetime` part throughout the string, leaving you with a tuple, then run `ast.literal_eval()` and convert each tuple to a `datetime.datetime()` object.

```py
import ast
import datetime

with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f.read().replace('datetime.datetime',''))

data
# [
#     {
#          'id': 1, 'name': 'abcd', 'date': (2021, 3, 13, 18, 54, 40, 314716),
#          'comments': None, 'status': 'Success'
#     }, 
#     {
#         'id': 2, 'name': 'efgh', 'date': (2021, 3, 14, 10, 4, 49, 9217),
#         'comments': None, 'status': 'Success'
#     }
# ]

data_w_datetime = [
    {k: datetime.datetime(*v) if k == 'date' else v for k, v in d.items()}
    for d in data
]

data_w_datetime
# [
#     {
#          'id': 1, 'name': 'abcd',
#          'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 13, 18, 54, 40, 314716),
#          'comments': None, 'status': 'Success'
#     }, 
#     {
#         'id': 2, 'name': 'efgh',
#         'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 14, 10, 4, 49, 9217),
#         'comments': None, 'status': 'Success'
#     }
# ]
```

Then, you can use `psycopg2` to load the data into Postgres without iterating, using `execute_values`.

```py
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values

columns = data_w_datetime[0].keys()
query = "INSERT INTO mytable ({}) VALUES %s".format(','.join(columns))

# extract values from each dictionary and put them in a list of lists
values = [[value for value in d.values()] for d in data_w_datetime]

conn = psycopg2.connect(**db_params) # specify your own connection params
cursor = conn.cursor()

execute_values(cursor, query, values)
conn.commit()
cur.close()
```